# How do I show ng-messages in a tooltip in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to add a tooltip which shows the corresponding ng-message when I hover mouse over it. When I run this code in an html file, span fields are not shown at all. What am I missing? Thanks

```
    <form name="userForm" novalidate>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" 
                ng-model="main.name"
                ng-minlength="5"
                ng-maxlength="10"
                ng-pattern='/^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$/'
                required>

            <div ng-messages="userForm.name.$error">
                <div ng-message="required">enter a name </div>
                <div ng-message="minlength">must be longer than 5</div>
                <div ng-message="maxlength">cannot exceed 10 characters</div>
                <div ng-message="pattern">must contain a combination of characters and numbers
                        <span class="fa fa-info-circle" data-toggle="tooltip" title="must contain a combination of characters and numbers"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Submit</button>
        </div>

    </form>
    <span class="fa fa-info-circle" data-toggle="tooltip" title="must contain a combination of characters and numbers"></span>
```

Comment: Have you included font-awesome.js Here is the working fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/7p5gdbn6/)

Comment: I did not include that. Now it works thank you!